# Cloud-to-Device message to raspi from IOThub

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, c#

What I am trying to do at this time is control LED lights on Raspi running windows 10.

so far I have an application running and waiting for a message to receive.  it works fine when I use Device explorer, but when I send from an API it does not process it (as if the message is null) but the strage thing is that my Device explorer is receiving the message.

The Raspi is connected successfully to Azure IOT hub and the message I receive on device Explorer when sending from postman:

> 2017-04-09 8:00:21 AM> Device: [Devicename], Data:[off]
>
> 2017-04-09 8:00:37 AM> Device: [Devicename], Data:[on]

But it never reaches my raspi when called from postman.

here is my Universal app

```
  DeviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(IotHubUri, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(DeviceId, DeviceKey));
  public async Task ReceiveCloudToDeviceMessageAsync()
        {
            CloudToDeviceLog = "Receiving events...";
            Debug.WriteLine("\nReceiving cloud to device messages from service");

        while (true)
        {
            Message receivedMessage = await DeviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
            if (receivedMessage == null) continue;

            var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
            CloudToDeviceLog += "\nReceived message: " + msg;

            if (msg == "on")
            {
                LedPin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            }

            if (msg == "off")
            {
                LedPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
            }

            await DeviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
        }
    }
```

---

and here is my API Call to IOThub from postman
https://IOThub.azure-devices.net/devices/devicename/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03

Comment: It is difficult to say why your Pi is not reciebing messages form postman. Is the incomming message supposed to be GET, POST, UPDATE, PATCH? Is it on a specific port? Hard to tell. What is the URL you are using to try and call the Pi. You are on the same network too .. right?